# Delaying all items except specific one

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

Let's say I have a stream of actions. They're either Prompts, Responses (to prompts) or Effects. They come at irregular intervals, but assume 1 second delay between each one.

On every `PROMPT` action I want to emit that action and a BEGIN action (let's say we want to show the message to user for N seconds). All other items should be delayed by N seconds, after which the END action fires (hiding the message) and everything continues.

This is my code for it (for https://rxviz.com/):

```
const { interval, from, zip, timer } = Rx;
const { concatMap, delayWhen } = RxOperators;

const PROMPT = 'P';
const RESPONSE = 'R';
const EFFECT = 'E';

const BEGIN = '^';
const END = '&';

const convertAction = action => (action === PROMPT) ? [PROMPT, BEGIN, END] : [action];

// Just actions coming at regular intervals
const action$ = zip(
  from([PROMPT, RESPONSE, EFFECT, PROMPT, RESPONSE, EFFECT, EFFECT, EFFECT]),
    interval(1000),
  (a, b) => a,
);

action$.pipe(
  concatMap(action =>
    from(convertAction(action)).pipe(
      delayWhen(action => (action == END) ? timer(5000) : timer(0)),
    ),
  ),
);
```

What I really want to do is for first `RESPONSE` action after `PROMPT` to not be affected by the delay. If it comes before END action, it should be shown right away. So, instead of

`P^      &REP^     &REEE`

I want to receive

`P^   R  &EP^R    &EEE`

How can I achieve it while keeping each `RESPONSE` after their corresponding `PROMPT`? Assume no events can come between `PROMPT` and `RESPONSE`.

Comment: You're `zip`ing a function? `(a, b) => a` - I'm surprised hat works. What does that do?

Comment: It takes values of array and spaces them by interval's time. `a` is first stream item (elements), `b` is second stream items (delays w/o value).

Comment: TIL if there's a function as the last argument, `zip` uses it to format the it's output... Neat! -- I've always done `zip().pipe(map())` for the same effect.

Comment: Is it fair to assume that the second prompt will always come after the first response or, more generally, that **Promp N+1** comes always after **ResponseN**?

Comment: @Picci yeah. They're basically indistinguishable, but every Prompt will have Response following it (after unknown time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it right, this is a very interesting problem to address with Observables streams. This is the way I would attack it.

First I would store in a constant `actionDelayed$` the result of your original logic, i.e. a stream where we have introduced, after each `PROMPT`, `BEGIN` and `END` actions divided by a delay.

```
const actionDelayed$ = action$.pipe(
  concatMap(action =>
    from(convertAction(action)).pipe(
      delayWhen(action => (action == END) ? timer(5000) : timer(0)),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Then I would create 2 separate streams, `response$` and `promptDelayed$`, containing only the `RESPONSE` actions before the delay was introduced and the `PROMPT` actions after the delayed was introduced, like this

```
const response$ = action$.pipe(
  filter(a => a == RESPONSE)
)
const promptDelayed$ = actionDelayed$.pipe(
  filter(a => a == PROMPT)
)
```

With these 2 streams, I can create another stream of `RESPONSE` actions emitted just after the `PROMPT` delayed actions are emitted, like this

```
const responseN1AfterPromptN$ = zip(response$, promptDelayed$).pipe(
  map(([r, p]) => r)
)
```

At this point I have just to remove all `RESPONSE` actions from `actionDelayed$` like this

```
const actionNoResponseDelayed$ = actionDelayed$.pipe(
  filter(a => a != RESPONSE)
)
```

and merge `actionNoResponseDelayed$` with `responseN1AfterPromptN$` to get the final stream.

The entirety of the code, to be tried with [rxviz](https://rxviz.com/) is this

```
const { interval, from, zip, timer, merge } = Rx;
const { concatMap, delayWhen, share, filter, map } = RxOperators;

const PROMPT = 'P';
const RESPONSE = 'R';
const EFFECT = 'E';

const BEGIN = '^';
const END = '&';

const convertAction = action => (action === PROMPT) ? [PROMPT, BEGIN, END] : [action];

// Just actions coming at regular intervals
const action$ = zip(
  from([PROMPT, RESPONSE, EFFECT, PROMPT, RESPONSE, EFFECT, EFFECT, EFFECT]),
    interval(1000),
  (a, b) => a,
).pipe(share());

const actionDelayed$ = action$.pipe(
  concatMap(action =>
    from(convertAction(action)).pipe(
      delayWhen(action => (action == END) ? timer(5000) : timer(0)),
    ),
  ),
  share()
);

const response$ = action$.pipe(
  filter(a => a == RESPONSE)
)
const promptDelayed$ = actionDelayed$.pipe(
  filter(a => a == PROMPT)
)
const responseN1AfterPromptN$ = zip(response$, promptDelayed$).pipe(
  map(([r, p]) => r)
)
const actionNoResponseDelayed$ = actionDelayed$.pipe(
  filter(a => a != RESPONSE)
)

merge(actionNoResponseDelayed$, responseN1AfterPromptN$)
```

The use of the `share` operator while creating `action$` and `actionDelayed$` streams allows to avoid repeated subscriptions to these streams when creating the subsequent streams used in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It may not work this way because you're using `concatMap`. As you know, it waits for the inner observable to `complete` before starting to process(to subscribe) the pending ones. It internally uses a buffer, such that if an inner observable is still active(did not `complete`), the emitted value will be added to that buffer. When the inner observable becomes inactive, the oldest value from the buffer is selected and a **new** inner observable will be created, based on the provided callback function.

There is also [`delayWhen`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/delayWhen.ts#L107), which emits a complete notification after all of its *pending* observables complete:

```js
// called when an inner observable sends a `next`/`complete` notification
const notify = () => {
  // Notify the consumer.
  subscriber.next(value);

  // Ensure our inner subscription is cleaned up
  // as soon as possible. Once the first `next` fires,
  // we have no more use for this subscription.
  durationSubscriber?.unsubscribe();

  if (!closed) {
    active--;
    closed = true;
    checkComplete();
  }
};
```

`checkComplete()` will check if there is a need to send a `complete` notification to the *main stream*:

```js
const checkComplete = () => isComplete && !active && subscriber.complete();
```

We've seen that `active` decreases in `notify()`. `isComplete` becomes `true` when the main source completes:

```js
// this is the `complete` callback
() => {
  isComplete = true;
  checkComplete();
}
```

So, this is why it does not work this way:

- the `PROMPT` action is used to create the `concatMap`'s first inner observable
- the observable emits 3 consecutive actions `[PROMPT, BEGIN, END]`
- the first 2 will get `timer(0)`, whereas the third one, `END`, will get (timer(5000)); notice that in this time, before the `PROMPT` action got emitted, the `isComplete` variable is set to `true`, because `from()` completes synchronously in this case
- so there is a `timer(5000)` that keeps the inner obs. active; then a `RESPONSE` is emitted from the `actions$` stream, but since there is no place for it yet, it will be added to the buffer and an inner obs. will be created when `timer(5000)` finally expires

---

A way to solve this might be to replace `concatMap` with `mergeMap`.